# Downloading file from internet over interrupted connection

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, windows-xp, mozilla

- I have net connection which doesn't provides stable connection.
- After every 8-10 minutes it get disconnected for 2-3 minutes and again connects back and this process goes on...
- It is very problematic to download a large file.
- Once the download gets interrupted it is very diffcult to resume most of the time it fails.
- -In mozilla and chrome once the net connection is interrupted the files which are being downloaded gets hanged(paused) automatically and then pausing and resuming back most of the times result in file download failure.
- I tried download manager for mozilla but download manager doesn't gives good result.
- Is there any way to download file which will get resume automatically after net connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tools like a download manager e.g [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org). However, what happens after it gets disconnected is important. In some cases, if you just get something like a login screen which some ISPs provide, this won't work by any means. This works most of the times if there is simply no connection to internet - no redirection or other ISP specific page.